# Query the DataCollector syscollector_collection_items XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to query a XML on the parameters column from the table syscollector_collection_items on the MSDB.

My problem is, when I query the following table,

```
select 
--ci.parameters.value('(.)[5]','varchar(100)') AS [Parameters],
ci.parameters.query('(/)') AS [Parameters]
FROM
msdb.dbo.syscollector_collection_sets AS cs
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syscollector_collection_items AS ci ON ci.collection_set_id=cs.collection_set_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syscollector_collector_types AS ct ON ct.collector_type_uid = ci.collector_type_uid
WHERE cs.is_system <> 1
FOR XML AUTO
```

I got the following result,

```
<cs>
  <Parameters>
    <ns:PerformanceCountersCollector xmlns:ns="DataCollectorType">
      <PerformanceCounters Objects="LogicalDisk" Counters="Avg. Disk sec/Read" Instances="_Total" />
      <PerformanceCounters Objects="LogicalDisk" Counters="Avg. Disk sec/Write" Instances="_Total" />
      <PerformanceCounters Objects="LogicalDisk" Counters="% Disk Time" Instances="_Total" />
    </ns:PerformanceCountersCollector>
  </Parameters>
</cs>
<cs>
  <Parameters>
    <ns:PerformanceCountersCollector xmlns:ns="DataCollectorType">
      <PerformanceCounters Objects="Processor" Counters="% Processor Time" Instances="_Total" />
      <PerformanceCounters Objects="Processor" Counters="% Privileged Time" Instances="_Total" />
    </ns:PerformanceCountersCollector>
  </Parameters>
</cs>
```

But I just want the "Objects" and "Counters" like a table results.

For example:

```
Objects     | Counters

LogicalDisk | Avg. Disk sec/Read

LogicalDisk | Avg. Disk sec/Write

LogicalDisk | % Disk Time

Processor   | % Processor Time

Processor   | % Privileged Time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `FOR XML AUTO`? This will transform a queries result into XML. If I read this correctly, you are trying to get *table-wise* data out of an XML...

Try it like this:

```
select perfCounter.value('@Objects','nvarchar(max)') AS Objects
      ,perfCounter.value('@Counters','nvarchar(max)') AS Counters
FROM
msdb.dbo.syscollector_collection_sets AS cs
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syscollector_collection_items AS ci ON ci.collection_set_id=cs.collection_set_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syscollector_collector_types AS ct ON ct.collector_type_uid = ci.collector_type_uid
CROSS APPLY parameters.nodes(N'/*:cs/*:Parameters/*:PerformanceCountersCollector') AS A(perfCounterCollector)
CROSS APPLY perfCounterCollector.nodes(N'*:PerformanceCounters') AS B(perfCounter)
WHERE cs.is_system <> 1
```

You must be aware, that the parameters in this table are very different in content, shape and structure.

As there are several `<ns:PerformanceCountersCollector>` elements you want returned as table, while each of them - again - includes several `<PerformanceCounters>`-elementes, I use `CROSS APPLY` with `.nodes()` to get hands on the first list and - hierarchically - one more `CROSS APPLY` to get the second list. What you need, are attribute values out of this second list.

Btw: I used `*:` to wildcard the namespace. It might be necessary to put this explicit. If you get any problems, just come back...

Comment: Hi @Shnugo, thank you for the reply. I run the query but don´t return any result, I change the where to use a default collection that have only one element and the select return blank.

Comment: @Leka Glad to help! Btw: Did it help?

Comment: Your answer opened my mind to try to solve the problem otherwise, but I still can not solve it